# Verificar se data e hora/minuto já expiraram

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema, ao subir meu site para o PHP 5.6 o código que eu utilizo para verificar se tal data e tal hora/minuto expirou simplesmente não está respeitando a hora, se for a data já fala que expirou sem verificar a hora/minuto. Alguém tem alguma solução?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE programada = 'sim'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

function NoticiasProgramadas($data){
    $dt_expira = str_replace("/", "-", $data);
    $dateInicio = date('Y/m/d G:i:s', strtotime($dt_expira));
    $timestamp_dt_expira = strtotime($dt_expira);
    $dt_atual = date("Y/m/d G:i:s");
    $timestamp_dt_atual = strtotime($dt_atual);

        $ret = '';
        if ($timestamp_dt_atual >= $timestamp_dt_expira) {
            $ret = "exp";
        }
    return $ret;
}
$d = NoticiasProgramadas("$row[postdate] $row[posthora]");
if ($d == "exp"){

//executa um código mysql

}
```

Comment: Dê um echo nas variaveis `$timestamp_dt_atual` e `$timestamp_dt_expira` para ver como elas estão antes do if;

Comment: 11-04-2018, 18:19 2018/04/11 23:19:01

Comment: Não, o timestamp mesmo, antes do `if ($timestamp_dt_atual >= $timestamp_dt_expira) `

Comment: Desculpe, eles estão assim 1523440560  1523483518

Comment: Voce pode simplificar nossa vida editando sua pergunta com os dados que esta usando para testar? Tipo o que é o `$data`, pois assim podemos testar seu codigo e ajudar

Comment: O $data não tem nada

Comment: Perdao, isso: `$row[postdate] $row[posthora]`

Comment: Vem do primeiro código lá em cima do **$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE programada = 'sim'";**

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75863/discussion-between-david-dias-and-carlos-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

Verifica como está a timezone do seu servidor on-line, em alguns casos antes de fazer qualquer coisa no PHP, você deve setar sua timezone para que dali em diante seu PHP trabalhe apenas com data e hora exatas, por exemplo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// daqui em diante tu bota o seu código...
```

Comment: Já está definido no mesmo arquivo *Brazil/East*